# Prediction Interval for the Kalman Filter

Tags: kalman-filter

I am considering using the Kalman filter for an online regression for the state space system
\begin{align}
\beta_t &= \beta_{t-1} + \eta_t \\
Y_t &= X_t \beta_t + \varepsilon_t
\end{align}

taking $\beta_t \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $Y_t \in \mathbb{R}$, and noise $\eta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, H_t)$, $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, Q_t)$. It is my understanding that my predicted observation $\hat{Y}_t \sim \mathcal{N}(X_t \hat{\beta}_{t|t-1}, X_t P_{t|t-1} X_t' + Q_t)$ for the prior estimates $\hat{\beta}_{t|t-1} = \hat{\beta}_{t-1|t-1}$ and $P_{t|t-1} = P_{t-1|t-1} + H_t$ (by the Kalman filter).

I am comfortable with my initialization approach for my parameters, but I have concerns with my prediction interval. I essentially take a z-score and the standard deviation from the distribution of $\hat{Y}_t$. Ideally, I would like to use an approach similar to the prediction interval for linear regression, where I would have to estimate $Q_t$ based on SS. It is not immediately clear to me how to do this however, since my approach here is online. Would it suffice to include an expanding/rolling window to calculate my sum of squares?

Thanks in advance!